# How to merge variables looping through by variable number in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a lot of variables seen in multiple conditions. I'd like to merge each variable by condition.

The example data frame is a simplified version of what I have (3 variables over 2 conditions).

```
VAR.B_1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
VAR.B_2 <- c(2, 2, 3, 4, 5,'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
VAR.B_3 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1,'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
VAR.E_1 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
VAR.E_2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
VAR.E_3 <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
Condition <- c("B", "B","B","B","B","E","E","E","E","E")

#Example dataset
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(VAR.B_1,VAR.B_2,VAR.B_3, VAR.E_1,VAR.E_2, VAR.E_3, Condition))
```

I want to end up with this, appended to the original data frame:

```
VAR_1  VAR_2   VAR_3 
1       2       1    
2       2       1    
3       3       1    
4       4       1    
5       5       1   
1       1       1      
1       2       1             
1       3       1             
1       4       1              
1       5       1
```

I understand that R won't work with i inside the variable name, but I have an example of the kind of for loop I was trying to do. I would rather not call variables by column location, since there will be a lot of variables.

```
##Example of how I want to merge - this code does not work
for(i in 1:3) {
     data$VAR_[,i] <-ifelse(data$Condition == "B", VAR.B_[,i], 
          ifelse(data$Condition == "E", VAR.E_[,i], NA))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for your situation:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
data %>% 
  mutate_all(as.character) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Condition) %>%
  filter(!is.na(value), value != "NA") %>%
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, paste0("\\.", Condition), "")) %>%
  group_by(Condition, key) %>%
  mutate(rowid = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  bind_cols(data)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 12
#> # Groups:   Condition [2]
#>    Condition rowid VAR_1 VAR_2 VAR_3 VAR.B_1 VAR.B_2 VAR.B_3 VAR.E_1
#>        <chr> <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>
#>  1         B     1     1     2     1       1       2       1      NA
#>  2         B     2     2     2     1       2       2       1      NA
#>  3         B     3     3     3     1       3       3       1      NA
#>  4         B     4     4     4     1       4       4       1      NA
#>  5         B     5     5     5     1       5       5       1      NA
#>  6         E     1     1     1     1      NA      NA      NA       1
#>  7         E     2     1     2     1      NA      NA      NA       1
#>  8         E     3     1     3     1      NA      NA      NA       1
#>  9         E     4     1     4     1      NA      NA      NA       1
#> 10         E     5     1     5     1      NA      NA      NA       1
#> # ... with 3 more variables: VAR.E_2 <fctr>, VAR.E_3 <fctr>,
#> #   Condition1 <fctr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data appears to have two kinds of `NA` values in it.  It has `NA`, or R's `NA` value, and it also has the string `'NA'`.  In my solution below, I replace both with zero, cast each column in the data frame to numeric, and then just sum together like-numbered `VAR` columns.  Then, drop the original columns which you don't want anymore.

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(VAR.B_1,VAR.B_2,VAR.B_3, VAR.E_1,VAR.E_2, VAR.E_3),
                      stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data[is.na(data)] <- 0
data[data == 'NA'] <- 0
data <- as.data.frame(lapply(data, as.numeric))

data$VAR_1 <- data$VAR.B_1 + data$VAR.E_1
data$VAR_2 <- data$VAR.B_2 + data$VAR.E_2
data$VAR_3 <- data$VAR.B_3 + data$VAR.E_3

data <- data[c("VAR_1", "VAR_2", "VAR_3")]
```

## Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
data.frame(lapply(split.default(data[-NCOL(data)], gsub("\\D+", "", head(names(data), -1))),
       function(a){
           a = sapply(a, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
           rowSums(a, na.rm = TRUE)
       }))
#   X1 X2 X3
#1   1  2  1
#2   2  2  1
#3   3  3  1
#4   4  4  1
#5   5  5  1
#6   1  1  1
#7   1  2  1
#8   1  3  1
#9   1  4  1
#10  1  5  1
#Warning messages:
#1: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
#2: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
#3: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```